# Can part of the a Multi-stage yaml be classified as Release pipeline?

Tags: azure, devops, rest

For my team where we have partner teams providing us SW pieces that need to be integrated on HW systems and tested together, our code footprint is small and hence churn is small, while number of changes from partner teams is frequent. In such a scenario, I see the need to trigger the release part of the yaml many more times than the build part. Is multi-stage pipelines the way to go? I want to trigger new release instances using RestAPI invoke only the Release stages on the YAML file, using  [AzureDevOps Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0).

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You don't *have* to use multi-stage pipelines to be able to trigger repeated releases, it just makes the management of the pipeline cleaner.

It's possible to create a pipeline that include a build stage and release stages for each of your environments, trigger the build stage (manually or based on a CI trigger), and then from that Pipeline "Run", deploy as many times as you see fit to whatever environments you like. That can be done from API or portal.

It's also possible to create a pipeline that is "release-only" - that is, it gets created manually, or as the result of seeing a specified build having been run.

Personally, I like the multi-stage build because it's a little easier to see what build created the release that you're deploying around. It's not a requirement, though.

Comment: When the build pipeline is building the final product to deploy to production it makes sense. In my case, I want to use one release pipeline to support, integration test execution, partner team drop verification and in house integration test gate.

Need to learn more about Environments.

Comment: Circling back to this. Environments in my case aren't applicable.